# Undefined reference to function in dll library after seemingly correct referencing

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, dll, mingw

I am trying to use an API that came with my motherboard (from manufacturer Advantech). The API consists of a .dll file, a .lib file, and a couple of header files. It can be downloaded at this link: http://support.advantech.com/support/DownloadSRDetail_New.aspx?SR_ID=1-RMSXG5&Doc_Source=Download

I am working in Windows 10, using Eclipse, which is itself using MinGW, with GCC.

I have written a very simple test program that includes the header files that came with the API, and calls a single function from the API:

```
// Headers that came with the API
#include "OsDeclarations.h"
#include "Susi4.h"

int main(void) {

    // Function that is part of the API, and is
    // declared in Susi4.h, and defined in Susi4.dll.
    SusiLibInitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

I have read the instructions for referencing a library directory and the library itself (called Susi4.dll), using the above toolchain. I am configuring the compilation and linking settings in the Eclipse GUI (by right-clicking on the project and going to "Properties"->"C/C++ Build"->"Settings"), but I can see what the resulting GCC command looks like from the Eclipse console. I assume copying and pasting these commands here is more helpful than attaching screenshots of my GUI, but do bear in mind that I am not writing these gcc commands; they are generated by Eclipse, off the back of my configuration settings in the GUI:

First off, the compilation command:

```
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\SUSI_C_test.o" "..\\src\\SUSI_C_test.c"
```

I have placed the header files (included with the API and referenced in the code) in the same source directory as SUSI_C_test.c, so this all seemingly compiles fine, and generates the object file SUSI_C_test.o.

Next, Eclipse moves on to try to link this object file with the library, with the following command:

```
gcc "-LC:\\Program Files\\Advantech\\SUSI\\SDK\\SUSI4\\lib\\x86" -o SUSI_C_test.exe "src\\SUSI_C_test.o" -lSusi4
```

The "x86" directory I have specified contains two files that came with the API I downloaded: Susi4.dll and Susi4.lib.

But the above linking command fails, and returns:

```
./src/SUSI_C_test.c:9: undefined reference to `SusiLibInitialize'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have checked that the function I am trying to call indeed exists in the .dll file, using the program "DLL Export Viewer" to view the different functions defined in Susi4.dll. See screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of DLL Export Viewer showing SusiLibInitialize present in library]

So what am I doing wrong? Many thanks in advance for any suggestions offered.

Comment: `"-LC:\\Program Files\\Advantech\\SUSI\\SDK\\SUSI4\\lib\\x86"` --> `-L"C:\Program Files\Advantech\SUSI\SDK\SUSI4\lib\x86"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately that didn't work (it returned the exact same error message). As the syntax was created by Eclipse, off the back of my setting the properties, presumably "-LC:\\..." is permissable - though admittedly peculiar - syntax.

Comment: In case it's useful, the API can be downloaded here: http://support.advantech.com/support/DownloadSRDetail_New.aspx?SR_ID=1-RMSXG5&Doc_Source=Download

Comment: Well, so it seems that you should add `-I` option to give compiler the path of `Susi4.h`

Comment: Thanks again LPs, but unfortunately both the header files did already compile correctly with the posted source code (they were placed in the same directory), and this successful compilation created the object file referenced in the posted gcc command for linking. Just in case, I just tried to compile and link in the same step, using command: gcc -L"C:\Program Files\Advantech\SUSI\SDK\SUSI4\lib\x86" SUSI_C_test.c -o SUSI.exe -lSusi4

...with no luck I'm afraid.

Comment: You will need a `.lib` file that matches the architecture you're building for.  Would you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40240961/edit) to show your full workflow (compile and link)? Also, are you compiling from within Eclipse, from MSYS, or from Cygwin with a mingw cross-compiler?  If MSYS or Cygwin, are you using a Makefile?  When you say "syntax was created by Eclipse", is that in an Eclipse configuration, a Makefile, or somewhere else?

Comment: Hi cxw, thanks for the suggestion. I have now elaborated on my workflow a little more in the question. But to answer your questions directly: I am working from within Eclipse, which is itself using MinGW. I am configuring the compilation and linking settings by right-clicking on the project in Eclipse, and clicking on Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings. The gcc commands pasted above are the ones displayed in the console when I hit "Build".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gcc can link against SUSI4.dll. Use FIND_LIBRARY(DLL_SUSI4 Susi4.dll ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/susi4) and TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(proggi ${DLL_SUSI4}) commands in your cmake script. An executable will be created. When you execute your program be shure that the dll is in the same path.

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance! Haven't logged in for a while.